# How to manage a large table with lots of inserts and selects?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, indexing

I have a table, namely X, with about 64 columns that stores online financial transactions. 
Every day millions of records are inserted into X. About 16 columns of X are queryable, that is to say, many system reports need to filter X's data based on the values of these 16 columns.

Having DB indexes for all of these 16 columns makes the insert action too slow. On the other hand, having no index on some columns makes some reports too slow as well.

So, here is the question. How I design the table X and its indexes to get the best performance on insert and report? I use oracle 11g DBMS.

Comment: Do you need real-time reporting, or are results from x hours/days ago satisfactory?

Comment: If there is no solution except reports with hours/days delay, I have to accept it, but online reports are preferable.

Comment: Why are there 64 columns on this table? My gut feeling says that this table is too wide and that some of this data should be spread over more tables.

Comment: If you tell us the structure of the table (including current indexes), maybe we can help.

Comment: @Colin'tHart: Regarding the fact that these 64 attributes belong to one entity, i.e. transaction (transaction date, time, amount, bank, card no, account no, etc.), it is not wise to spread them among tables.

Comment: @Colin'tHart: In addition, currently there is no index on this table due to quick insert on the table. To get reports, I fetch X's data and insert them into another table namely Y with the same columns but indexes, periodically. This approach is proved to be inefficient because of the overhead of jobs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to partition the table. Instead of creating one gigantic table, create one per day, week or month and a view which joins all of them for queries. Alternatively, Oracle has support for partitioned tables (but whether that's available depends on your version of Oracle).

When you insert data, insert into the correct partition. That way, the index to update will be much smaller. The drawback is that you will need a lot more space for indexes because the index values will be duplicated.

On the positive side, queries might be much faster since the DB can read tables in parallel when they are on different disks.

Also note that SQL databases don't scale to just any size. Consider a clustered or cloud database instead. They have other drawbacks but they can handle any number of records (as long as you have enough physical space for the servers, that is).

Comment: There's no reason a SQL database can't scale to millions of inserts per day. What's a "Cloud database"?

Comment: The main reason is that the time to insert or query data grows as you add data. Eventually, any operation on the database will just take too long. Yes, the term "cloud database" isn't exact. Would "map-reduce capable data store" be better?

Comment: map-reduce capable is a good term. But I beg to differ in opinion. A well designed SQL database can scale far further than most of us realise.

Answer (score 1):

Recommemdations:

1. Try to normalize table if possible.
2. Create clustered index if does not exist. (INT64 will do in your case)
3. If indexed columns are large in size and follow some pattern, try moving distinct data to separate lookup table and replace with surrogate key reference, it will reduce index size.
4. Create indexes with multiple keys. ( reduce number of indexes )
5. Partition the table due to the fact that in a year you will get approximately 360 million records.